# How to figure out the column names programmatically using Netezza SQL, where the column values matches a preset value

Tags: sql, netezza

All,

I have a table like this in netezza. The table has about 30 attributes for different products. I need to find the column names ( in this example column name "attr1" and "attr2") which have "YES" values.

Generally if a column has "YES" as the value, then it would be so for all the rows in the table.

upc upc_desc attr1  attr2   attr3   attr4   attr5
1   cake1    YES    NO  NO  YES
2   cake2    YES    NO  NO  YES
3   cake3    YES    NO  NO  YES
4   cake4    YES    NO  NO  YES
5   cake5    YES    NO  NO  YES
6   cake6    YES    NO  NO  YES

Question: How to figure out the column names programmatically using Netezza SQL, where the column values matches a preset value ?

Thanks !!

Comment: "Generally if a column has "YES" as the value, then it would be so for all the rows in the table."  Generally or always?  If not always, which do you want, any column with a "YES" in any row, or any column with a "YES" in all rows?

Comment: Sorry i shouldn't have used "Generally". I want a column with a "YES" in all rows. What i meant to say was this: the attribute columns have either "YES" or "NO" or nulls in all rows. - Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the output that you want?

Comment: In this case the output would look like a table: attar_col could be the col name, values will be attr1 and attr4. I'm not able to show this properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to transpose data .
These kind of questions were already answered in SO.

[Transpose rows to columns based on ID column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714304/transpose-rows-to-columns-based-on-id-column).

[Netezza aggregation issue (pivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855366/netezza-aggregation-issue-pivot)

Hope this helps! If you want more help please reply.